# How to get time range using current time in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time

I need to get time for 2 hours before the current time and time for after two hours to current time.

**2hr+current time<-----before--------currentTime-------after------->2hr+current time**

Ex: Below code, I use to get the details between a date range, likewise I need to get details between the above time range

`"SELECT * FROM VEH
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(SCHEDULED_ON, '%d/%m/%Y') >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND STR_TO_DATE(SCHEDULED_ON, '%d/%m/%Y') <= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)"`

Comment: What do you want to do with the range?

Comment: In sql tabel has columns which has starting times,that column data type is TIME,I need to get records from that table which has starting time between above mention range according to current time

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. [Edit] your question with a sample query that might use this range (and what you would expect to get from that query) and that might make it possible to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is statement for MySQL, should be similar to SQL.

```
SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR as `2hrbefore`, 
       NOW() + INTERVAL 2 HOUR as `2hrafter`
```